# Writing an encoding method from the decoding method

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, reverse-engineering

I have been working on reverse engineering some code for a couple days and I've gotten quite stuck. It's basically just a logic problem that I can't wrap my min around, me and my partner are both stuck on this.

The setup:

```
function decrypt(s) {

var r = "";
var tmp = s.split("9812265");
s = unescape(tmp[0]);
k = "4849604567466";

var temp, temp2, temp3, tempf;
for( var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

    temp = parseInt(k.charAt(i%k.length));
    temp2 = s.charCodeAt(i);
    temp3 = (temp^temp2)-3;
    tempf = String.fromCharCode(temp3);
    r += tempf;

}

return r;

}
```

I have this function, and the loop is what we can't reverse. What is meant to happen is to turn HTML into a bunch of characters then escape those characters. I wrote a method that can escape any string, so that part is easy. The loop that preforms the change is just to hard of a logic problem for me.

Comment: Just unroll the loop by hand for a string of length 2 or 3 and it should be obvious how to write the `encrypt` function. And no, I'm not going to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function encrypt(output)
{

  var SecretNumber = "4849604";
  var returnValue = "";

  for(var n = 0; n < output.length; n++)
  {
    returnValue += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(SecretNumber.charAt(n%SecretNumber.length))^(output[n].charCodeAt(0))+3);
  }
  return escapeAny(returnValue) + 9812265 + (escapeAny(SecretNumber));
}
```

Paired with the function for escaping string mentioned earlier:

```
function escapeAny(string)
{

  var list1 = [];
  var list2 = [];

  for(i = 16; i < 255; i++)
  {

    list1[i-16] = ("%" + i.toString(16).toString());
    list2[i-16] = (unescape(list1[i-16]));

  }

  var charAr = string.split('');
  var newChat = [];
  for(i = 0; i < charAr.length; i++)
  {

    var currentChar = charAr[i];
    var charNumber = list2.indexOf(currentChar);
    var ret = list1[charNumber];
    newChat[i] = ret;

  }

  String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
  };

  return newChat.join().replaceAll(",", "");

}
```

This solution seems to have worked well.